# What is meant by homopolar coordinate?

Tags: motor-controller, three-phase

I am reading a textbook about power electronic converters which describes that for a motor with poles connected in a wye configuration, that

If the homopolar component is zero,
$$
V_A+V_B+V_c=0
$$
If we add the homopolar component,
$$
\frac{V_A+V_B+V_c}{3}=V_0
$$

What is this "homopolar component" it speaks off? Unfortunately it doesn't speak of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tri-phase case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetrical_components).

In a 3-phase system, homopolar "coordinate" = 0 shows that the 3 phases are exactly the same voltage ...   (phased with +/- 120° and zero).
If this is not the case, than the system has a "homopolar" voltage.
This is a component of "[Fortescue](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_de_Fortescue)" transform.
The other two components are "direct" and "inverse" coordinates system.